# Openstack: Nested Stack creation via dashboard

Tags: openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

I have a heat template containing nested stack resources, which i am able to deployed successfully via heat-api. Can the same yaml (nested stack creation be done) be used via dashboard??

Comment: Have you raised this on Openstack community group - https://ask.openstack.org/en/questions/?

Answer (score 0):

No.

When we are launching the stack with nested heat templates, the heat service will search for nested heat templates in the current directory. So if we launch the stack through dashboard with nested templates it will throw the error "Unable to find the nested file". So we need to use only CLI and API for launching stack with nested templates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to upload yaml file or URL referring to yaml file.You can also upload environment variable on dashboard horizon.In my case I create cluster with similar computes with a single file.